# How to get root permissions for FSCopyObjectAsync like Finder

Tags: objective-c, file-io, file-permissions

I'm writing file manager, what using `FSCopyObjectAsync` for file copying.

How i can get permissions and call it function with permissions like Finder in objective-c?

I don't want to use Helper Tool because i need a callback function to display progress in my app.

Answer (score 0):

First see the [Authentication, Authorization, and Permissions Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Authorization/Authorization.html). Then see the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

This has nothing to do with whether you use a helper app. A helper process can communicate with the UI process in a variety of IPC ways. That's an architectural decision, but however you go, you should minimize the size and complexity of the program that runs as root, and the length of time it has root privileges.

Comment: and how to make helper process? please easy example (main app runs helper process, what authorizes user like Finder and creates folder at "/"

Comment: This is too big a question for StackOverflow. There is no short answer to "how do I correctly and securely communicate between a privileged and unprivileged process." You need to start by reading the above linked documents. The section that covers helper processes is called "Authorizing in a Factored Application." After you have read the above documents, you can ask questions related to them, but they are the correct place to find examples.